# What happens after the execution of a handler function on the SIGCHLD signal in C?

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, system-calls

I was wondering what exactly happens after the execution of a handler on a signal in C, more specifically on the SIGCHLD signal.

I'm actually building a shell and I need to do this:

1. User enters a command with "&" as the last argument
2. A new process is created with fork
3. The parent process returns to the main function and wait for a new input from the user
4. The child process executes in the background
5. The child process ends and SIGCHLD is triggered
6. The parent process handles the death of his child

My code do all of these points, but behaves in a strange way at the very end when the handler function returns.

### My implementation

**Main loop**

```
int
main()
{

    // SIGNALS HANDLING :
    sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGQUIT, NULL, NULL);


    // Current location
    char* path = malloc(PATHMAX);
    int argc;

    char** argv;

    // main loop
    while(1) 
    {
        getcwd(path, PATHMAX);
        printf("%s$ ",path);

        argc = 0;

        // Parsing
        argv = malloc(MAX_INPUT); // user's input is limited to 100000 characters
        getParameters(argv, &argc);


        // First we check if the user wants to execute the task in background
        if ( strcmp(argv[argc-1],"&") == 0 ) {

            // builtin functions can't be executed in background:
            int isExit = (strcmp(argv[0],"exit") == 0) ? 1 : 0;
            int isCd = (strcmp(argv[0],"cd") == 0) ? 1 : 0;

            if(isExit || isCd) {
                printf("Built-in functions can't be executed in background. \n");
            } else {
                // Execute the job in background

                // First we delete the last arg
                argv[argc-1] = NULL;
                argc--;

                execBackground(argv,argc);
            }

        } else {

            // Execute built-in functions
            if(!(exeBuiltin(argv, argc))) {
                // Execute jobs if no builtin functions were executed
                exeJob(argv,argc);
            }

        } 


        free(argv);



    }




    return 0;
}
```

**User's input processing**

```
// max 100000 characters
char input[MAX_INPUT];


// read keyboard inputs
fgets(input,MAX_INPUT,stdin);
```

**Built-in functions (cd and exit)**

```
int exeBuiltin(char** argv, int argc) {
    // execute builtin functions if it exists
    char* builtin[2];
    builtin[0] = "exit";
    builtin[1] = "cd";

    // run through the arguments
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        // exit
        if (strcmp(argv[i],builtin[0]) == 0) {
            exitBuiltin(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        } else if (strcmp(argv[i],builtin[1]) == 0) {
            // cd
            if (argc >= 2) {
                cdBuiltin(argv[i+1]);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static void cdBuiltin(char* path) {
    if(chdir(path) == -1) {
        printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));
    };
}


static void exitBuiltin(int signal) {
    exit(signal);
}
```

**Link between signal and handler:**

```
struct sigaction sa;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = 0;
sa.sa_handler = child_handler;

sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL);
```

**Handler:**

```
static void child_handler(int sig)
{
    int status;
    /* kills process 
     pid is a global variable that is set when I call fork() */
    if(waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != -1) {

        if (status == 0)  // Verify child process terminated without error.  
        {
           // success  
           printf("\nBackground job exited with code 0\n");
        }

        if (status == 1)      
        {
            // error
            printf("\nBackground job exited\n");
        }

    }


    return;
}
```

### The problem

My problem occurs when I call something like:

```
sudo apt-get update &
cd ../
```

Then when the sudo command terminates (the handler is called and prints "Background job exited with code 0"), even though  the command "cd ../" is already executed it gets executed **again**.

The ouput looks like:

```
$ /home/ubuntu/workspace$ sudo apt-get update &
$ /home/ubuntu/workspace$ cd ../
$ /home/ubuntu$
Background job exited with code 0
$ /home$
```

Additional information:

cd is a builtin function which only does: `chdir(path)` with a path given, and the path is simply output with a `printf("%s$",path)` at the beginning of every loop in the main (after a command has been called).

### The question

In order to understand what the real problem is, I believe that I should understand what happens at the end of my child_handler function.

If I'm at a certain point in the code with the main process, say waiting on the user input, and the background process dies, child_handler is called and then what? Does it change anything for the main process or is it still a the same point in the code, waiting for an input?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Not sure whether hat solves your problem (because I cannot see the code), but most blocking system calls can be *re-started* by the system when interrupted by a signal (depending on the SA_RESTART flag).

Comment: How is your shell going to handle a shell script that runs 2 or more commands in background (e.g. `long-running-command file1.txt & long-running-command file2.txt & long-running-command file3.txt`)? What about a pipeline (`ls | grep -v 'xy.*t' | wc`)?  There'll be more than one process running in the background, so a single global variable is going to be woefully inadequate.  However, this is tangential to your current problem.

Comment: You are going to need to show more code.  The problem is not in the code you show, so we need to see more code.  Please review how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]), and then create a command that does sufficient to reproduce your problem without invoking `sudo` or `apt-get` (`sleep` is a good tool for simulating slower programs).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler In fact I don't have to worry about multiple background processes because it is specified in my exercice sheet (college exercice) that the shell will be limited to one foreground and one background process.

Comment: @tofro So, the foreground process would start the code over from the beggining of the main?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I edited my question I hope there is enough of my code now. Thank you.

Comment: Nah, nothing like "re-starting the program". Restarting happens on system call level - A blocking system call like `read` may be re-started by the system when it is interruppted by a signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ChrisDodd said, the problem was that a system call (fgets), was interrupted by the death of the background process and caused undefined behaviour.

Therefore, I solved my problem by adding the following flag to my handler:

```
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
```

As the documentation says it will:

> Provide behavior compatible with BSD signal semantics by making certain system calls restartable across signals.

Thus no more issue with fgets.

Comment: This implies that your actual bug is that you're not checking the return value of `fgets` for errors -- if the signal interrupts it, it will return NULL and set the error indicator (which you need to check with `ferror` and reset with `clearerr`)

Comment: I did check the error and I had one but I couldn't figure out how to deal with it. But yes, the error was "interrupting system call" or something like that so it should have popped something in my brain.

Answer (score 1):

One definite problem is that you are calling `printf` in your signal handler, and `printf` is not async-safe, so if the SIGCHLD happens while in any library function (such as `fgets` waiting to read a line of input perhaps?), you get undefined behavior.  Perhaps corrupting the stdio file buffers and causing it to act as if the input was duplicated.

You need to *very* careful how you write the code in your signal handler, making sure it cannot call (directly or indirectly) and non-async-safe library function, and ensuring that all the code is itself async-safe with respect to any side effects in other parts of your program.

Comment: Ok thank you, but in fact I tried to remove all the printf and nothing changes, it still "recalls" the cd function and I end up with this:
/home/ubuntu$/home$